# heroku build failed. "mongoUrl"://"mongodb........" syntax error and more

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, build, syntax-error

I must admit, I'm quite a beginner in programming. 
I'm doing an online course where I want to connect an api using heroku and mongodb. I think I've got some problems following the instructions because the video is older than the current state of heroku and mongodb.
I managed to `git push heroku master` but when I got to heroku and start the app it says an error occured. Then I ran `heroku logs --tail`, I checked my build and this showed

```
-----> Node.js app detected



-----> Creating runtime environment



       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

       NODE_ENV=production

       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

       NODE_VERBOSE=false



-----> Installing binaries

       engines.node (package.json):  8.10.0

       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)



       Resolving node version 8.10.0...

       Downloading and installing node 8.10.0...

       Using default npm version: 5.6.0



-----> Installing dependencies

       Installing node modules (package.json)



       > uws@9.14.0 install /tmp/build_63fff292b65e6a987cf3dc9195527d57/node_modules/uws

       > node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0





       > core-js@2.6.10 postinstall /tmp/build_63fff292b65e6a987cf3dc9195527d57/node_modules/core-js

       > node postinstall || echo "ignore"



       added 608 packages in 32.816s



-----> Build

       Running build



       > slacky-slack@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_63fff292b65e6a987cf3dc9195527d57

       > babel src -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0



SyntaxError: src/config/index.js: Unexpected token, expected , (7:21)

   5 |   // "mongoUrl": "mongodb://localhost:27017/chat-api",

   6 |   "port": process.env.PORT,

>  7 |   "mongoUrl": mongodb://esteP:<CEpalacios2019>@chattychatchat-shard-00-00-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-01-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-02-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=chattychatchat-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&m=majority ,

     |                      ^

   8 |   "bodyLimit": "100kb"

   9 | }

  10 | 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! slacky-slack@1.0.0 build: `babel src -s -D -d dist --presets es2015,stage-0`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the slacky-slack@1.0.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.5odQG/_logs/2019-10-19T12_28_48_165Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed



       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
```

FYI this index.js file looks like `this import mongodb from 'mongodb'; export default { // "port": 3005, // "mongoUrl": "mongodb://localhost:27017/chat-api", "port": process.env.PORT, "mongoUrl": "mongodb://esteP:<**********>@chattychatchat-shard-00-00-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-01-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-02-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=chattychatchat-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority", "bodyLimit": "100kb" }`

I don't understand most of these errors, except for the syntax error, but I don't know where is the problem.
Thanks for all the help you can give to this noob :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit `src/config/index.js` and change this:

```
"mongoUrl": mongodb://esteP:<CEpalacios2019>@chattychatchat-shard-00-00-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-01-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-02-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=chattychatchat-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&m=majority
```

to this:

```
"mongoUrl": "mongodb://esteP:<CEpalacios2019>@chattychatchat-shard-00-00-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-01-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017,chattychatchat-shard-00-02-6ydjb.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=chattychatchat-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&m=majority"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help man! I did that :( and the problem persists

Comment: same error, the thing is that, first I tried to push through terminal without the "", it showed an error, I corrected it and placed the "" and the push worked fine, but when I opened the app in heroku it shows as if the "" aren't there. In other words, in the index.js file, the "" are there but in heroku they arent, does that make sense?